# How can i find null values in a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a data table say i have a column like x which is primary key so i should get the row where this x values in empty.thanx in advance

Comment: can be primary key null in datatable?

Comment: I think he means the DataTable class of System.Data

Comment: ya correct  its not sql table

Answer (score 1):

<strike>SELECT x, y
      FROM table
     WHERE y IS NULL</strike>

Whoops, my bad:

`dataTable.Select("FieldName IS NULL")`

Comment: Its a DataTable?.so where i should this query

Comment: but where i will be getting the output

Comment: It will filter your `DataTable`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the WriteXml()- method, which writes the actual content of the DataTable-Object as XML. One is then able to parse it with LINQ to xml.